# How do I show a picture on different pages using Laravel Route Prefix?

Tags: laravel, image, url, routes, prefix

I have a image file. More than one pages is using this image file.
Image is properly displayed in dashboard. Because this page not use Route Prefix.
For example; Brand page is using Route Prefix. The picture is not displayed on this page.

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
Route::get('dashboard', [homeAppController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');

//web.php
Route::controller(brandController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'brand', 'as' => 'brand.'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'index')->name('index');
        Route::get('/create', 'create')->name('create');
        Route::get('/store', 'store')->name('store');
        Route::get('/show/{id}', 'show')->name('show');
        Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('edit');
        Route::get('/update/{id}', 'update')->name('update');
        Route::get('/destroy/{id}', 'destroy')->name('destroy');
    });
});

//Dashboard
<img alt="" src="../assets/media/svg/brand-logos/{{ $data->logo }}"/>

//brand/show    
<img class="rounded-0" src="../assets/media/svg/brand-logos/{{ $brand->logo }}" alt=""/>
```

The picture is not displayed on this page. Because route started with brand prefix. For example; .../brand/assets/...

Comment: use asset method check here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-asset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening cause you are using relative paths, so it would be different on routes.

You can use full url like `foo.com/bar.jpg`
or Simply just `/bar.jpg` (starting `/` is important)

or if you're on Laravel blade, you can also use

```php
<img src="{{ asset('bar.jpg') }}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket! I wrote the exact path to the image. Its working.